# Can't make request from localhost:xxxx to localhost:yyyy

Tags: symfony, xampp, localhost, port

I have an **Xamp** server running on **MacOs 10.14.6**.
I activated port forwarding on it like that :

```
localhost:8080 -> 80 (Over SSH)
localhost:8443 -> 443 (Over SSH)
```

I can navigate to my website on `localhost:8443` with no issue.

I have another server running Symfony 5.4 available at `localhost:8000`. I can navigate to this website with no issue too.

But from the 'Xamp hosted' website, I'm not able to make a request to the 'Symfony hosted' server. I have a "*Connection Refused error*".

I tried to request both `127.0.0.1:8000` and `localhost:8000` : same behavior.
I tried to set the Symfony server to listen to a different port too : same behavior.

It only works when I make a request to the real local ip address (like `192.168.1.34:8000`). The problem is that this IP is not stable so I'd like to make the localhost work properly.

What could be the cause of this error ?
What can I do to use localhost hostname for my requests ?

Comment: Did you forward port 8080 or port 8000?

Comment: @WanderNauta I'm not sure of your suggestion. Do you mean to forward on Xamp ? forwarding from where to where ? (8080 is already forwarded to 80)

Comment: Edit your `VirtualHost` file and find out if that specific host is listening on all interfaces (something like `VirtualHost *:8000`) or it's bound to the LAN ip only. Change and restart if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the task manager section for applications running on the same port which may when you want to request a connection on the server you will use it will get a similar rejection. I think it's more or less like that

Comment: It may be helpful to provide instruction on how to perform this operation